# Which type of URL is better for Laravel?

Tags: php, path, laravel

If I use relative paths, like this:

```
<script src="../../../public/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

They don't work with Laravel!

When I use Root Relative Paths like this:

```
<script src="/sis_colgate/public/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Everything works fine but if I have to change location, I have to modify all of them!

If I use Laravel URL::base()

```
<?php echo'<script src="'.URL::base().'/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>'; ?>
```

It works fine but on client-side (Dreamweaver) I can't see the images or the links for my scripts.

Is there any other way to do this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The most correct option is to use the URL::base().

But you should not use dreamweaver to see your front end.

You can use it to write the code, but remember that dreamweaver is not a browser and it will never be.

To see the result of your code you have to setup a apache server or upload the code to a server.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `URL::to_asset('js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js');` in Laravel 3 and `URL::asset('js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js');` in Laravel 4.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with relative URL's is it depends on what your current location is. You should consider using [`URL::to_asset()`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/laravel/url.php#L240) which is the best choice for your current situtation. It uses absolute path and the base path is configurable just incase you plan on hosting your assets elsewhere (say, amazon S3/Cloudfront).

Answer (score 1):

**Dear all**

One could also do this in Laravel 4:

```
<script src="<?php echo asset('js/main'); ?>"></script>
```

or the ***blade templating*** equivalent

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
```

Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver allows you to set a base folder in its preferences, so you should be able to use absolute paths. Generally your base folder should be at the /sis_colgate/public/ directory, not anything above it. That way it doesn't depend on the directory structure of your current computer.